# Do all Mac programs work on an iPad?

Tags: mac, ipad

Can I count on all Mac programs working on an iPad? Or do only "apps" written specifically for the iPad work on an iPad, e.g. does Quicken for Mac works on an iPad?

Answer (score 5):

Mac OS X and iOS (the OS used in iPhone/iPad) are completely different systems: for starters, OS X runs on the x86-64 architecture (Intel CPUs) while iOS runs on ARM CPUs.

This alone makes apps incompatible; also, the architecture and libraries of the OSes are different, as per this Stack Overflow question: [Difference between iPhone development and Mac OSX development](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6553305/1071869).

Answer (score 1):

Apple's OS X (desktops and laptops) and iOS (ipod touch, iphone, ipad) are two very different operating systems. Apps for one are not designed to run on the other.